# How to setup push notification for development?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I've developed an app for ios and it has been published on the app store.
The push notification system worked fine in development but now, i receive no notification at all.
Before publishing, i've generated the Development Provisioning Profiles associated with an App Id having enabled the push and configurated the Production Push SSL Certificate. I've downloaded the Production Push SSL Certificate and installed it in my keychain access, exported it and its private key, converted them to pem and united them in a unique pem file, which i uploaded to my server containing the php script which send the notifications.
I've changed the server in my php script to the one of production (ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195).
Still the script seems to send the notification and doesn't fire any error.

What i'm missing?

Here's my php script:

```
<?PHP
/* Here there's Code to retrieve device tokens and put it in a variable $deviceToken from     my online database and then...*/


$message = "Message to be sent";    
$payload = '{
                "aps" : 

                    { "alert" : "'.$message.'",
                      "badge" : 1,
                      "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"
                    } 
            }';

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'ck.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'secret');

// se l'app è già sull'appstore togliere sandbox e lasciare solo gateway.push.apple.com:2195
// invece di gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
if(!$fp){
    print "Failed to connect $err $errstrn";
    return;
} else {
    print "Notifications sent! </br>";
}

foreach($devArray as $deviceToken){
    $msg = chr(0) . pack("n",32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . pack        ("n",strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    print "sending message :" . $payload . "n to device:".$deviceToken."</br>";
    fwrite($fp, $msg);
}
fclose($fp);
```

?>

Comment: Did your app has been compiled with a production provisioning? You didn't mention it

Comment: Maybe the deviceTokens are not correct. Have you checked from `print "sending message :" . $payload . "n to device:".$deviceToken."</br>";
    `?

Comment: Yes, has been compiled with a production provisioning, and published on the appstore. I though about the tokens. The line you quote report lines like "sending message :{ "aps" : { "alert" : "message", "badge" : 1, "sound" : "bingbong.aiff" } }n to device:c016118d79b914dee92d34b66aa334f4ce2a29ccf77026046638632e61b7538d" and all seems ok...

Comment: Doesn't the device token have some white spaces? I'm not sure, but I believe this makes a difference to send the notification.

Comment: No, i trim it to avoid that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One last step to do when setting up push is be sure you didn't mixed production and development device token! 
In my case, in my db the first device token the push was send to, was a development one. When this happens, Apple server kill the connection, avoid any other notification to be sent. Thanks Apple!

Answer (score 1):

Cause you have to regenerate the PEM with a valid "Production Push SSL Certificate" not with the "Development Push SSL Certificate".

EDIT: Sorry i've read two times the wrong row. The procedure looks good, i post the php code that i always use, it looks very similar but you can try to edit it.

```
<?php
      // Passphrase for the private key (ck.pem file)
      // $pass = ”;
      // Get the parameters from http get or from command line
      $message = 'Testo Notifica Push';
      $badge = 1;
      $sound = 'default';

      // Put your private key's passphrase here:
    $passphrase = '';

      // Construct the notification payload
      $body = array();
      $body['aps'] = array('alert' => $message);

      if ($badge)
            $body['aps']['badge'] = $badge;
      if ($sound)
            $body['aps']['sound'] = $sound;

      /* End of Configurable Items */

// Put your device token here (without spaces):
$deviceToken = '20afc981ce9f0c63b5beb83d561d086a1338b2d42dd6defef67e4b7dbabe72b9';

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', 'cert.pem');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $passphrase);

// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client(
    'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err,
    $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

if (!$fp)
    exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

echo 'Connected to APNS' . PHP_EOL;

// Construct the notification payload
      $body = array();
      $body['aps'] = array(’alert’ => $message);

      if ($badge)
            $body['aps']['badge'] = $badge;
      if ($sound)
            $body['aps']['sound'] = $sound;

// Encode the payload as JSON
$payload = json_encode($body);

// Build the binary notification
$msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $deviceToken) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

if (!$result)
    echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
else
    echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;

// Close the connection to the server
fclose($fp);
?>
```

Comment: thank you very much, there's an interesting logging part i'll check to see if the php script fire some error

Comment: i had no luck unfortunately ^^

Comment: no error at all? "Connected to APNS. Message successfully delivered" appear?

Comment: If you retrieve Tokens from a DB check to TRIM the string and check that it's the correct one cause it can change from develop mode and production mode.

Comment: no error, string appear and the device tokens are perfectly stored in the db.. This is driving me mad... maybe it's a certificate problem. My name is, immagine, Minnie Mouse and i develop with my Mac where i am Minnie Mouse. If i go to the provisioning portal, in "Certificates" there'a a "Development" certificate bearing the name of who paid for the member program, that is Mickey Mouse, and a "Distribution" certificate bearing the name of the society Topolina S.r.l. Maybe, this is the problem?

Comment: No, i don't think this can be a problem cause i'm in the same situation and everything is working good. The SSL protocol on the server works correctly? it's the same of the development phase? I ask this because the major hosting solutions in italt doesn't allow the ssl protocol or every call to the 2195 port (like Aruba and Register).

Comment: how can i check this? In development all went well and the call in php was still to the 2195 port, isn't? A similar situation wouldn't have raised some errors in the stream_socket_client call, causing not to display the "connected to apn string"?

Comment: If the server is the same of the sandbox call my solution was not right. One time i encounter this problem cause i've installed on my device the development and the production versions of the app. Have you tried to remove twice versions and reinstall from AppStore, remove and reallow the notification flag of the app in the Notifications menu of Settings?!?

Comment: Yes! I tried Also a fresh new install in a device on which The app was never installed...